# Resample function doesn't work for Landsat-8 NDVI 8-days product in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using **Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 8-Day NDVI Composite** in Google Earth Engine and I want to export it with the projection same as code editor (EPSG:3857). However, when I add the reprojected image in the map, it appeared very weird.
The original image looks like:
[image]

but after reprojection the image looks like:

[image]

I also tried to use **Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 8-Day TOA Reflectance Composite** to directly calculate NDVI and reproject it, but it still failed.

Another problem is the NDVI calculated by image is different from products provided by Google, is there any differences in calculating NDVI?

The code is here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a88b1b6da7529e3a10e642e28002f4f7